# how to find the dimension of a CSR matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `tfidf` matrix of type `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`

How do I find the number of rows and number of columns of it in Python 3?

I tried converting it to a dense one and  then finding the length of a row like this

`len(tfidf_matrix.todense())` but it outputs 1 which is not right.

Comment: `tfidf_matrix.shape`?

Comment: @jeremycg ah yes you are right. If you post it as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the function `matrix.get_shape()`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.get_shape.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.get_shape